# JavaScript form submitting when not validating

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following JS to validate a form when submitting:-

```
function validate()
{
   if( document.square.PosX.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please pick where in the square you think we are" );
     document.myForm.PosX.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}

<form name="square" action="save_results.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
         <input type="text" id="PosX" name="PosX">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When the field 'PosX' is empty and I hit Submit I see the alert popup in the browser, but when I click OK the form still submits.

How can I prevent it from actually submitting unless the form fields are not empty?

Thanks

Comment: FYI `onsubmit="return(validate());"` should be `onsubmit="return validate();"`, and `return( true );` should be `return true;`

Comment: @j08691, not an issue. You could write `return((((validate()))))` and the interpreter would remain unfazed.

Comment: Thanks, corrected that but still not fixing my original issue with the form submitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a copy&paste error in your script:
See the form name: `document.square.PosX.focus() ;`

```
function validate()
{
   if( document.square.PosX.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please pick where in the square you think we are" );
     document.square.PosX.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because you're referencing a form named `myForm` when it's actually named `square.` If you look at the error console when you run the code, you'll see you get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PosX' of undefined` because of this.

Change the line `document.myForm.PosX.focus() ;` to `document.square.PosX.focus();`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L4fAB/)**